# Relationship of additive and triangulated structures in the triangulated cateogry

Tags: ct.category-theory, triangulated-categories

In the triangulated category $T$, say we have  two distinguished triangles: $$X \xrightarrow{f} Y \rightarrow C_f \rightarrow X[1], $$ $$ X \xrightarrow{g} Y \rightarrow C_g \rightarrow X[1]$$ Of course these data uniquely determines the triangele $$X \xrightarrow{f+g} Y \rightarrow C_{f+g} \rightarrow X[1]$$ The natural question is if one  can write down some kind of "reasonable" relationship between $C_{f+g}$ and $C_{f}$ and $C_{g}$? (seems like natural approach $f+g=\triangledown \circ (f\oplus g) \circ \triangle$ does not lead to anything reasonable. Maybe the fact that cone construction is not functorial, does not allow the nice interplay between additive and triangulated structures)

Comment: Probably the answer is 'no', but how to prove it?

Comment: The prototype for the notion of "mapping cone" is the notion of cokernel, so maybe it would be helpful to ask yourself: given two maps between, say, abelian groups, is their a relationship between the cokernel of the sum and the cokernel of the indiviudal maps?

Comment: **is there. (whoops)

Comment: @Dylan, in my experience, the analogy of mapping cones with cokernels is usually misleading.

Comment: Assuming the category is $k$-linear you can do a more general thing by taking the cone of $\lambda f  + \mu g$ for $\lambda,\mu \in k$. It gives a family of objects specializing to $C_f$, $C_g$, and $C_{f+g}$. So, one can say that all these objects are in the same deformation family.

Comment: The triangulated structure is extrinsec, in the sense that there are different triangulations on the same additive category (see Paul Balmer, Triangulated categories with several triangulations, available at the author homwpage). It seems to me that there is no relation between the triangulated structure and the additive structure, since otherwise different triangulations would lead to different additive structures. 